# How to integrate a CSR bluetooth dongle with pybluez library

Tags: python-3.x, bluetooth, pybluez

I was to connect to a bluetooth device using the pybluez python library.  I'm using the CST bluetooth dongle (similar to [this](http://www.dx.com/p/ultra-mini-bluetooth-csr-4-0-usb-dongle-adapter-black-143276#.VuHJSJyLTIU))  However I get the following:

```
>>> from bluetooth import discover_devices
>>> discover_devices()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
discover_devices()
File "C:\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\bluetooth\msbt.py", line 15,in discover_devices
devices = bt.discover_devices(duration=duration, flush_cache=flush_cache)
OSError: The RPC server is unavailable.
```

I'm on Windows 10, the dongle is functioning correctly and I can pair up.  Any advice/tips on how to make the dongle visible to the library?

Comment: Perhaps this may be relevant: [Discovering bluetooth devices IOError: The RPC server is unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389334/discovering-bluetooth-devices-ioerror-the-rpc-server-is-unavailable/32394499)

Comment: The key difference is "OSError" (this question) vs "IOError" (linked question). We have a similar problem, wondering if there was a resolution?